# jq: error: syntax error, Unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <builtin>, line 29: )

Tags: jq, macos-catalina

Started seeing this issue with jq suddenly out of the blue for my system where its failing for simplest of use-cases:

```
$ echo '{"foo": 0}' | jq .
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <builtin>, line 29:
  )
jq: 1 compile error
```

Here's a description of my environment:

OS and Version: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, 64-bit
jq versions: 1.6, 1.5, 1.4

I tried installing jq with brew (`brew install jq`) as well as using binaries directly provided [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) for OSX 64-bit and getting same error. It works strangely however with jq-1.3 but thats a pretty old version missing some important filters like `gsub`.

Comment: Something's wonky. Please provide the output of `x='{"foo": 0}'; echo "$x" | od -t x1; echo "$x" | jq .`

Comment: ```$ x='{"foo": 0}'; echo "$x" | od -t x1;echo "$x" | jq .```

Gives:
```0000000    7b  22  66  6f  6f  22  3a  20  30  7d  0a
0000013
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <builtin>, line 29:
  )
jq: 1 compile error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted this issue in jq github repo and got [prompted](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2264#issuecomment-774684289) for issue with ~/.jq file. Indeed my ~/.jq file had the said syntax error. Fixing my ~/.jq file fixed the issue.